# Function returns 0

Tags: excel, vba, function, variables

I am writing a file import procedure. I have my column numbers mapped between the two files as a function

I pass in a variable called c which is the column on the import file, i then use case select in a function to output a different variable name with the mapped column numbers (which I am probably doing incorrectly

The case select works in that it stops at the correct case, passes over the cNew = x and then jumps to the end of the function

The issue I am having is that the new variable always returns 0. Variables and function are dimmed as integers

```
For c = 2 To 19
cNew = cMapped(c)
MsgBox (cNew)
Next c

Function cMapped(c As Integer) As Long
Select Case c
    Case Is = 1
    cNew = 1
    Case Is = 2
    cNew = 3
    Case Is = 3
    cNew = 2
    Case Is = 4
    cNew = 7
    Case Is = 5
    cNew = 5
    Case Is = 6
    cNew = 16
    Case Is = 7
    cNew = 19
    Case Is = 8
    cNew = 21
    Case Is = 9
    cNew = 27
    Case Is = 10
    cNew = 30
    Case Is = 11
    cNew = 6
    Case Is = 12
    cNew = 11
    Case Is = 13
    cNew = 10
    Case Is = 14
    cNew = 32
    Case Is = 15
    cNew = 28
    Case Is = 16
    cNew = 33
    Case Is = 17
    cNew = 99
    Case Is = 18
    cNew = 50
    Case Is = 19
    cNew = 8
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: oh just to add I have set the function  as long, as integer and without an as statement with no avail. If I don't set it at all rather than getting 0 I get "empty"

Comment: You're not returning anything in your function. Instead of assigning cNew =... you should be returning that value.

Comment: either put `cMapped = cnew` at the bottom just before end function or change all of the cnew to cMapped.

Comment: Thank you both. Amended cNew to cMapped as suggested and worked as expected. Can't believe out of all the things I tried that was not one of them. How do i flag comments as correct / useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one. You have to return the value this way. And I think `select` looks this way in VBA.

```
Function cMapped(c As Integer) As Long

Select Case c
    Case 1:
    cNew = 1
    Case 2:
    cNew = 3

End Select
cMapped = cNew

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case c
  Case 1
    cNew = 1
  Case 2
    cNew = 2
  ...
return cNew
...
```

Does this work better?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I have not tested this but as the one above worked I would assume this would too.

Answer (score 0):

as answered by user10798192 and  Michael Puckett II I was quite obviously not returning anything properly

Here was the adjusted code;

```
   For c = 2 To 19
     cNew = cMapped(c)
     MsgBox (cNew) 
     Next c
```

And the amended function

```
Function cMapped(c As Integer) As Long
Select Case c
    Case Is = 1
    cMapped = 1
    Case Is = 2
    cMapped = 3
    Case Is = 3
    cMapped = 2
    Case Is = 4
    cMapped = 7
    Case Is = 5
    cMapped = 5
    Case Is = 6
    cMapped = 16
    Case Is = 7
    cMapped = 19
    Case Is = 8
    cMapped = 21
    Case Is = 9
    cMapped = 27
    Case Is = 10
    cMapped = 30
    Case Is = 11
    cMapped = 6
    Case Is = 12
    cMapped = 11
    Case Is = 13
    cMapped = 10
    Case Is = 14
    cMapped = 32
    Case Is = 15
    cMapped = 28
    Case Is = 16
    cMapped = 33
    Case Is = 17
    cMapped = 99
    Case Is = 18
    cMapped = 50
    Case Is = 19
    cMapped = 8
End Select
End Function
```